# Hold array elements with multiple properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I currently have this JavaScript array. I have used this sorted list of numbers to generate a list of tournament brackets where a team's seed is taken into account.

The problem is that to carry out my seeding algorithm, I work out the 2 teams in the final, and use their seed to work out the previous matches, which would be using `seeds[0]` and `seeds[1]` giving me `1` and `2`. But this causes problems when I'm trying to manually enter the name of the team.

Here is the current array:

```
var seeds = [
      1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
]
```

I would like to use something where I can refer to `seeds[0].id` to get their seed number, and when it comes to printing out their name for the tournament brackets I can use `seeds[0].name` such that:

```
var seeds = [
    { id : 1, name : "Team 1" },
    { id : 2, name : "Team 2" },
    etc
]
```

What do you think the best way to do this would be? The main problem is that when creating a list of matches to be placed into the brackets which are seeded, I am using the seed number, and then creating a new array of the seeds in the correct seeded order so that I can just print the brackets as `newSeeds[0] vs newSeeds[1]` & `newSeeds[2] vs newSeeds[3]` and so on.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: So what's the question exactly?  Why not just use the second array above, as written?

Comment: Whats the question? You seem to have posted the correct answer to the only question I can find.

Comment: @AlexWayne If I try to do this and write `document.write(seeds[0].name)` nothing appears whatsoever so surely I am writing something wrong?

Comment: @germainelol Creating an array like that works just like you think it does: http://jsfiddle.net/Squeegy/pHdfp/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this way,

Create a class seed which has all the properties of seeds as instance variables.

When creating the seeds array, keep pushing those seed objects into the array instead of any random hashmap.

So when you iterate over the array, you can call methods on each object(seed object) which can do the desired thing for you.